# Spark SQL dataframe: best way to compute across rowpairs

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark DataFrame "deviceDF" like so :

```
ID    date_time            state  
a     2015-12-11 4:30:00     up  
a     2015-12-11 5:00:00     down  
a     2015-12-11 5:15:00     up  
b     2015-12-12 4:00:00     down  
b     2015-12-12 4:20:00     up  
a     2015-12-12 10:15:00    down  
a     2015-12-12 10:20:00    up  
b     2015-12-14 15:30:00    down
```

I am trying to calculate the downtime for each of the IDs. I started simple by grouping  based on id and separately computing the sum of all uptimes and downtimes. Then take the difference of the summed uptime and downtime.

```scala
val downtimeDF = deviceDF.filter($"state" === "down")
  .groupBy("ID")
  .agg(sum(unix_timestamp($"date_time")) as "down_time")  

val uptimeDF = deviceDF.filter($"state" === "up")
  .groupBy("ID")
  .agg(sum(unix_timestamp($"date_time")) as "up_time")  

val updownjoinDF = uptimeDF.join(downtimeDF, "ID")  

val difftimeDF = updownjoinDF
  .withColumn("diff_time", $"up_time" - $"down_time")
```

However there are few conditions that cause errors, such as the device went down but never came back up, in this case, the down_time is the difference between current_time and last_time it was down.

Also if the first entry for a particular device starts with 'up' then the down_time is difference of the first_entry and the time at the begining of this analysis, say 2015-12-11 00:00:00. Whats the best way to handle these border conditions using dataframe? Do I need to write a custom UDAF ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you can try is to use window functions. While this is usually not the fastest possible solution it is concise and extremely expressive. Taking your data as an example:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp

val df = sc.parallelize(Array(
    ("a", "2015-12-11 04:30:00", "up"), ("a", "2015-12-11 05:00:00", "down"), 
    ("a", "2015-12-11 05:15:00", "up"), ("b", "2015-12-12 04:00:00", "down"), 
    ("b", "2015-12-12 04:20:00", "up"), ("a", "2015-12-12 10:15:00", "down"),
    ("a", "2015-12-12 10:20:00", "up"), ("b", "2015-12-14 15:30:00", "down")))
  .toDF("ID", "date_time", "state")
  .withColumn("timestamp", unix_timestamp($"date_time"))
```

Lets define example window:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{coalesce, lag, when, sum}

val w = Window.partitionBy($"ID").orderBy($"timestamp")
```

some helper columns

```scala
val previousTimestamp = coalesce(lag($"timestamp", 1).over(w), $"timestamp")
val previousState = coalesce(lag($"state", 1).over(w), $"state")

val downtime = when(
  previousState === "down",
  $"timestamp" - previousTimestamp
).otherwise(0).alias("downtime")

val uptime = when(
  previousState === "up",
  $"timestamp" - previousTimestamp
).otherwise(0).alias("uptime")
```

and finally a basic query:

```scala
val upsAndDowns = df.select($"*", uptime, downtime)
upsAndDowns.show

// +---+-------------------+-----+----------+------+--------+
// | ID|          date_time|state| timestamp|uptime|downtime|
// +---+-------------------+-----+----------+------+--------+
// |  a|2015-12-11 04:30:00|   up|1449804600|     0|       0|
// |  a|2015-12-11 05:00:00| down|1449806400|  1800|       0|
// |  a|2015-12-11 05:15:00|   up|1449807300|     0|     900|
// |  a|2015-12-12 10:15:00| down|1449911700|104400|       0|
// |  a|2015-12-12 10:20:00|   up|1449912000|     0|     300|
// |  b|2015-12-12 04:00:00| down|1449889200|     0|       0|
// |  b|2015-12-12 04:20:00|   up|1449890400|     0|    1200|
// |  b|2015-12-14 15:30:00| down|1450103400|213000|       0|
// +---+-------------------+-----+----------+------+--------+
```

In a similar manner you cna look forward and if there is no more records in a group you can adjust total `uptime` / `downtime` using current timestamp.

Window functions provide some other useful features like window definitions with `ROWS BETWEEN` and `RANGE BETWEEN` clauses.

Another possible solution is to move your data to RDD and use low level operations with `RangePartitioner`, `mapPartitions` and sliding windows. For basic things you can even `groupBy`. This requires significantly more effort but is also much more flexible.

Finally there is a [`spark-timeseries`](https://github.com/cloudera/spark-timeseries) package from Cloudera. Documentation is close to non-existent but tests are comprehensive enough to give you some idea how to use it.

Regarding custom UDAFs I wouldn't be to optimistic. UDAF API is rather specific and not exactly flexible.

Comment: Thanks, I wasnt aware of window functions